# Python using re to create spaces between characters except for those in square brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a data frame:

```
d1  ={'letters':['ABCDE[NOT]FGH', 'CCGF[NOT]HI', 'MPJ[NOT]L', 'MNA[NOT]PLJKAJSHD']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

df1:

```
letters
0   ABCDE[NOT]FGH
1   CCGF[NOT]HI
2   MPJ[NOT]L
3   MNA[NOT]PLJKAJSHD
```

I want to create a space between each character except for those between the [ ].

Desired output:

```
letters
0   A B C D E [NOT] F G H
1   C C G F [NOT] H I
2   M P J [NOT] L
3   M N A [NOT] P L J K A J S H D
```

I have tried:

```
matching = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z []]+(?![^{]*})(\w)', r'\1', i)

df1['letters'].apply(lambda x: matching)
```

But this does not seem to work.
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append a space to each `[...]` substring or any other char found in the string and then `rstrip` the result:

```py
>>> df1['letters'].str.replace(r'\[[^][]*]|.', r'\g<0> ', regex=True).str.rstrip()
0            A B C D E [NOT] F G H
1                C C G F [NOT] H I
2                    M P J [NOT] L
3    M N A [NOT] P L J K A J S H D
Name: letters, dtype: object
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3EVA8H/1).

Another way is to add spaces around any char other than those that are matched with the `\[[^][]*]` pattern, and then `str.strip()` the result:

```py
>>> df1['letters'].str.replace(r'(\[[^][]*])|.', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else f" {x.group()} ", regex=True).str.strip()
0                A  B  C  D  E [NOT] F  G  H
1                      C  C  G  F [NOT] H  I
2                            M  P  J [NOT] L
3    M  N  A [NOT] P  L  J  K  A  J  S  H  D
Name: letters, dtype: object
```

The `(\[[^][]*])|.` regex matches and captures into Group 1 a `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char, or any char other than a line break char, and replaces with the Group 1 value if it was captured or with "space" + match value + "space" otherwise.

The `str.strip()` removes leading/trailing spaces if any arise from the replacing operation.

**Non-Pandas code**

```py
import re
# Solution 1
text = re.sub(r'\[[^][]*]|.', r'\g<0> ', text).rstrip()

# Solution 1
text = re.sub(r'(\[[^][]*])|.', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else f" {x.group()} ", text).strip()
```

Comment: You beat me to to it! I was just about to post this, https://regex101.com/r/9jnbB4/1/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is a bit different though, I think you do not even need those groups. It will still require a post-processing step to remove the trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit wildly inefficient, you could use this and avoid post-processing:

```regex
(?=(?!^)[^\[\]]*?\[|[^\[\]]+$)
```

- `(?=` - start a lookahead

  - `(?!^)` - do not assert the start of the string
  - `[^\[\]]*?\[` - assert any position leading up to a opening bracket `[`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\[\]]+$` - assert any position which is not a bracket leading up to the end of the line
- `)` - close the lookahead

https://regex101.com/r/zoHEne/1/

**Note:** The regex101 example has trailing spaces only because of the multiline. Test each line one at a time to see no trailing spaces.

Comment: I think this is less universal, it will only work with a single `[...]` substring, you can see it if you use `ABCDE[NOT]FGH[AFG]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I do realize that but it does work for the presented data set

Comment: There is always a problem with this kind of approaches, one has to assume the brackets are paired. If they are, it is more or less fine. Else, it will break.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed. There are plenty of details open for discussion which I doubt OP has considered such as: Should `a[b][c]d` become `a [b] [c] d` or `a [b][c] d`? I just wanted to challenge myself to a solution which is unique from yours. Your answers have encouraged me to continue participating in the `regex` tag for 2 years now. Before, I would abstain from regex due to my limited understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import pandas as pd, re
d1 = {'letters':['ABCDE[NOT]FGH', 'CCGF[NOT]HI', 'MPJ[NOT]L', 'MNA[NOT]PLJKAJSHD']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1['letters'] = df1['letters'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(re.findall('\[\w+\]|\w', x)))
```

```
                         letters
0          A B C D E [NOT] F G H
1              C C G F [NOT] H I
2                  M P J [NOT] L
3  M N A [NOT] P L J K A J S H D
```